# Django parler: error when same translation for different languages

Tags: django, django-admin, django-parler

**EDIT**: my bad, i had:

```
translations = TranslatedFields(
    title=models.CharField(_('Title'), unique=False, max_length=40, null=False, blank=False)
)
```

**I had `unique=True`**, that was the reason, so now the question is how do I require unique title for each language (for example, so there is only one 'Sport' for english language but not in general including all the translations), can I add constraint directly in `models.py`?

**---------------------------------------------------**

I've just added *django-parlel* to my project and I'm wondering is it my bad or it's really **impossible to have same translation more then once**.

Case I'm trying to add translation for Polish language for word "Sport", in polish it would be "Sport", just same as in English (which I have by default in app). When trying to add this getting error both when adding from **admin panel** and when loading **fixture**. I know that i might leave it blank and it won't really be that bad however I need to have translation for each single word.
I'm assuming there is a constraint in parlel

[Error in Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpQIh.png):

```
Polish:
  Please correct the error below.
    Interests Group Translation with this Title already exists.
    Interests Group Translation with this Title already exists.
Title: [Sport]
```

django-parlel settings:

```
PARLER_LANGUAGES = {
    None: (
        {'code': 'en',}, # English
        {'code': 'pl',}, # Polish
        {'code': 'uk',}, # Ukrainian
    ),
    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['en'],
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class InterestsGroup(TranslatableModel):
    '''
    Group for storing similar interests (that are related to same topic)
    '''
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        title=models.CharField(_('Title'), unique=True, max_length=40, null=False, blank=False)
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Interests Group')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Interests Groups')
        ordering = ['id']
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? [See here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: @starball I think in my case image is a must ;((

Comment: Yes, I'm not asking you to remove the image. I'm asking you to _add_ a transcription!

Comment: you cannot have same translation for same lang

Comment: Can you post your language settings here, and model definition?

Comment: @vdboor posted and updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this solved my problem:

```
translations = TranslatedFields(
    title=models.CharField(_('Title'), unique=False, max_length=40, null=False, blank=False),
    meta={'unique_together': [('language_code', 'title')]}  # unique title for each single language/translation
)
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct approach! Otherwise the `title` has to be unique across all translations of the object, but you likely want it to be unique per language.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this [modeltranslation package](https://pypi.org/project/modeltranslation/)

I also used django-parler and I think it's better to use modeltranslation instead of django-parler. There will not be a problem about writing same text in different languages and it is also have tabbed view like django-parler